# Using Ruby to access a SQLAnywhere 12 database(either DBI or SQLAnywhere gem)

Tags: ruby, dbi, sqlanywhere

I am trying to use either the gem dbi or sqlanywhere gem to access a SQLAnywhere 12 database on a Windows 64-bit machine. The database is running locally. I have been completely unsucessful & any assistance would be great appreciated.

```
Ruby Version = ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06) [i386-mingw32] 
*** LOCAL GEMS *** 

bigdecimal (1.1.0) 
builder (3.2.0) 
childprocess (0.3.9) 
chunky_png (1.2.7) 
commonwatir (4.0.0) 
compass (0.12.2) 
dbd-odbc (0.2.5) 
dbd-sqlanywhere (1.0.1) 
dbi (0.4.5) 
deprecated (2.0.1) 
epoxy (0.3.1) 
ffi (1.4.0 x86-mingw32) 
fssm (0.2.10) 
hoe (3.5.1) 
io-console (0.3) 
json (1.5.4) 
libxml-ruby (2.6.0 x86-mingw32) 
methlab (0.1.0) 
mini_magick (3.2.1) 
minitest (2.5.1) 
multi_json (1.6.1) 
nokogiri (1.5.6 x86-mingw32) 
rake (0.9.2.2) 
rautomation (0.7.3) 
rdbi (0.9.1) 
rdoc (3.9.5) 
rubygems-update (2.0.1) 
rubyzip (0.9.9) 
s4t-utils (1.0.4) 
sass (3.2.7) 
selenium-webdriver (2.31.0) 
sequel (3.46.0) 
sqlanywhere (0.1.6 x86-mingw32) 
subexec (0.0.4) 
typelib (0.1.0) 
user-choices (1.1.6.1) 
watir (4.0.2 x86-mingw32) 
watir-classic (3.4.0) 
watir-webdriver (0.6.2) 
websocket (1.0.7) 
win32-api (1.4.8 x86-mingw32) 
win32-process (0.7.1) 
win32screenshot (1.0.7) 
windows-api (0.4.2) 
windows-pr (1.2.2) 
xml-simple (1.1.2)
```

When using DBI

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'dbi' 

DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:Agency')
```

returns

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:300:in `block in load_driver': Unable to load driver 'ODBC' (underlying error: uninitialized constant DBI::DBD::ODBC) (DBI::InterfaceError) 
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize' 
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:242:in `load_driver' 
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:160:in `_get_full_driver' 
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:145:in `connect' 
        from dbi_test.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

When using sqlanywhere

```
require 'sqlanywhere' 

api = SQLAnywhere::SQLAnywhereInterface.new() 
SQLAnywhere::API.sqlany_initialize_interface( api ) 
api.sqlany_init() 

sqlanywhere_test.rb:65: [BUG] Segmentation fault 
ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06) [i386-mingw32] 

-- Control frame information ----------------------------------------------- 
c:0027 p:---- s:0109 b:0109 l:000108 d:000108 CFUNC  :sqlany_init 
c:0026 p:0011 s:0106 b:0106 l:000093 d:000105 BLOCK  sqlanywhere_test.rb:65 
c:0025 p:0080 s:0104 b:0104 l:000103 d:000103 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/assertions.rb:96 
c:0024 p:0054 s:0094 b:0094 l:000093 d:000093 METHOD sqlanywhere_test.rb:64 
c:0023 p:0046 s:0090 b:0090 l:000089 d:000089 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:947 
c:0022 p:0025 s:0084 b:0084 l:000083 d:000083 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb:17 
c:0021 p:0090 s:0080 b:0080 l:000068 d:000079 BLOCK  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:787 
c:0020 p:---- s:0074 b:0074 l:000073 d:000073 FINISH 
c:0019 p:---- s:0072 b:0072 l:000071 d:000071 CFUNC  :map 
c:0018 p:0124 s:0069 b:0069 l:000068 d:000068 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:780 
c:0017 p:0020 s:0061 b:0060 l:000050 d:000059 BLOCK  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:565 
c:0016 p:---- s:0056 b:0056 l:000055 d:000055 FINISH 
c:0015 p:---- s:0054 b:0054 l:000053 d:000053 CFUNC  :each 
c:0014 p:0053 s:0051 b:0051 l:000050 d:000050 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:563 
c:0013 p:0189 s:0045 b:0045 l:000044 d:000044 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:746 
c:0012 p:0013 s:0035 b:0035 l:000034 d:000034 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:909 
c:0011 p:0012 s:0032 b:0032 l:000023 d:000031 BLOCK  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:896 
c:0010 p:---- s:0029 b:0029 l:000028 d:000028 FINISH 
c:0009 p:---- s:0027 b:0027 l:000026 d:000026 CFUNC  :each 
c:0008 p:0068 s:0024 b:0024 l:000023 d:000023 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:895 
c:0007 p:0029 s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:884 
c:0006 p:0022 s:0016 b:0016 l:000015 d:000015 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:21 
c:0005 p:0033 s:0012 b:0011 l:000c44 d:000010 BLOCK  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:326 
c:0004 p:0036 s:0009 b:0009 l:000008 d:000008 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:27 
c:0003 p:0026 s:0006 b:0006 l:000c44 d:000005 BLOCK  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:325 
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH 
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:001d0c d:001d0c TOP   

-- Ruby level backtrace information ---------------------------------------- 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:325:in `block in autorun' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:27:in `run_once' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:326:in `block (2 levels) in autorun' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:21:in `run' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:884:in `run' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:895:in `_run' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:895:in `each' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:896:in `block in _run' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:909:in `run_tests' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:746:in `_run_anything' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:563:in `_run_suites' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:563:in `each' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:565:in `block in _run_suites' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:780:in `_run_suite' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:780:in `map' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:787:in `block in _run_suite' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb:17:in `run' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:947:in `run' 
sqlanywhere_test.rb:64:in `setup' 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/assertions.rb:96:in `assert_nothing_raised' 
sqlanywhere_test.rb:65:in `block in setup' 
sqlanywhere_test.rb:65:in `sqlany_init' 

-- C level backtrace information ------------------------------------------- 
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll(ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15) [0x77aaf8b1] 
C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll(WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x43) [0x75771194] 
C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll(WaitForSingleObject+0x12) [0x75771148] 
C:\Ruby193\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll(rb_vm_bugreport+0xf9) [0x62e5c69d] 
C:\Ruby193\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll(rb_name_err_mesg_new+0x17a) [0x62d3a856] 
C:\Ruby193\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll(rb_bug+0x2f) [0x62d3b533] 
C:\Ruby193\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll(rb_check_safe_str+0x1a4) [0x62dee738] 
 [0x004011e6] 
C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll(GetProfileStringW+0x12aa3) [0x757b003f] 
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll(RtlKnownExceptionFilter+0xb7) [0x77b074df] 

-- Other runtime information ----------------------------------------------- 

* Loaded script: sqlanywhere_test.rb 

* Loaded features: 

    0 enumerator.so 
    1 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/encdb.so 
    2 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/iso_8859_1.so 
    3 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/trans/transdb.so 
    4 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/rbconfig.rb 
    5 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/compatibility.rb 
    6 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb 
    7 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb 
    8 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/errors.rb 
    9 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/version.rb 
   10 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb 
   11 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/platform.rb 
   12 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb 
   13 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb 
   14 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb 
   15 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb 
   16 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb 
   17 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb 
   18 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ubygems.rb 
   19 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb 
   20 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb 
   21 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/prettyprint.rb 
   22 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pp.rb 
   23 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/assertions.rb 
   24 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb 
   25 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb 
   26 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/date_core.so 
   27 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date/format.rb 
   28 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb 
   29 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/path_support.rb 
   30 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/utf_16le.so 
   31 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so 
   32 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/trans/single_byte.so 
   33 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb 
   34 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlanywhere-0.1.6-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlanywhere.so 

[NOTE] 
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries. 
Bug reports are welcome. 
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html 


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. 
Please contact the application's support team for more information. 
>Exit code: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved for the sqlanywhere gem. I have been unable to successfully use dbi.

Basically I was running the 32-bit version of Ruby and did not have dbcapi.dll within the following folder structure - `C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 12\Bin32`. I had another test machine (32-bit) SQL Anywhere where I copied the dbcapi.dll on the 64-bit test machine. My path was already set.

To summarize - when running ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06) [i386-mingw32] to use the sqlanywhere gem (sqlanywhere-0.1.6-x86-mingw32) ensure the following:

dbcapi.dll exists in the following folder structure - `C:Program Files\SQL Anywhere 12\Bin32`
Make sure your path includes `C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 12\Bin32`